# How can I start a bash script 20 seconds after startup?

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, autostart

I got a bash script that stops a program, mounts the pi and starts the program again. I would like to start it on startup, but after the program itself started. So my idea was to simply wait some time (20 or 30 seconds) and start the script then (`task.sh`). Any idea how I can do that? Or any other idea how to solve this? (let the script wait for the program to start won't work i guess, cause then the script would restart after the program is restarted, right?)

Thanks and Greetings,
Elias

Comment: Launch the script at startup and put `sleep 20` as your first command.

Comment: And how do I launch it at startup? With `rc.local`?

Comment: Yes, that could be an option. There's plenty of information on how to do that depending on your distribution.

Comment: I tried it a couple of times with rc.local and it didn't work. Simply wrote `sudo ./tash.sh` or `sudo sh /home/pi/task.sh` before `exit 0`, is that right? Or is there a way to simply define the script as autostart or something like that?

Comment: Here's is some examples for [rh7](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-make-custom-script-to-run-automatically-during-boot/) and [debian](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts). Make sure to use one better suited for your distro,

Comment: Inside task.sh, do a `ps` on the process you want it to stop, and just sit in a loop (with a `sleep 1` inside perhaps), until the start time of that process is more than 20s in the past.

Comment: Would that restart the script every time the program starts?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the help, but I solved it myself following this tutorial:

create a new file in `/etc/init.d/`, I'll call it *example* in this.

So:

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/example
```

This will be a file that will be executed after raspberry pi startup.
The code for this file is the following:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          Für welches Programm ist das Script?
# Required-Start:    
# Required-Stop:     
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Kurze Beschreibung
# Description:       Längere Beschreibung
### END INIT INFO
 
# Actions
case "$1" in
    start)
        # START
        ;;
    stop)
        # STOP
        ;;
    restart)
        # RESTART
        ;;
esac
 
exit 0
```

Because I wanted this script to start `/home/pi/task.sh` at startup and reboot, I simply put `/home/pi/task.sh` before the `;;` after `# START` and `# RESTART`

If you've done that, save it and exit it. Then type

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/example
```

to make the script executable. The last step is to define the runlevels:

```
sudo update-rc.d example defaults
```

After that you can reboot and see if it works.

I hope that made it clear for everyone :)

(And just for me: https://jankarres.de/2014/07/raspberry-pi-autostart-von-programmen-einrichten/ :D)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a Debian / Debian derivative distro (Ubuntu / Mint / Etc) here's how to achieve the result you look for.

Create your script in the path you've suggested using any text editor (here I use the simple nano):

```
nano /home/pi/task.sh
```

Paste into your task.sh:

```
sleep 40
/home/pi/pi_video_looper/disable.sh
mount -a
/home/pi/pi_video_looper/install.sh
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x /home/pi/task.sh
```

Make sure the script works running it:

```
/home/pi/task.sh
```

Once you're sure that the script works fine edit your rc.local:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

A key concept here is that whatever you put in rc.local will be executed with root permissions.
*For this reason there is no need to use sudo.*

Add before exit 0 the following:

```
/home/pi/task.sh
```

Reboot and test

Comment: Thanks for this detailed discription, but sadly it isn't working... Do I need a & after `/home/pi/task.sh`? Or what could I do else? I tried the script itself a couple of times, and it is 100% working. You got any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Let's try to understand what is happening...
Please paste the script in your question.

Comment: sleep 40
cd /home/pi/pi_video_looper
sudo ./disable.sh sudo mount -a
cd /home/pi/pi_video_looper
sudo ./install.sh